# python find the index of the last value in a list that is not a "None"

Tags: python, list

I have a list with values and a bunch of `None`. For example:

```
a = ['a', 'b', None, 4, 5, None, 5, 4, None, 7, None, None, None, None]
```

I'm looking for the quickest (shortest number of characters) way to find the index of, in this case `7`, the last non-`None` value.

`9` should be the output.

Comment: Saying "quickest (shortest code)" makes it unclear whether you want the approach with the fastest performance or the one with the fewest number of characters.  Sometimes you're lucky and they're the same, but often not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's hard to beat something very obvious, like:

```
def get_last(a):
  for i, e in enumerate(reversed(a)):
    if e is not None:
      return len(a) - i - 1
  return -1
```

Note that [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) simply creates a reversed iterator, it doesn't copy the list. And since list access is fast, this should be Good Enough even for very large lists.

The subtraction in the inner return compensates for the fact that `reversed()` causes the `enumerate()` to walk the input list backwards, hence the index `i` inside the loop is from the end.

Comment: I think the `next` version of this looks equally nice.

Comment: @unwind: I did :-) but that answer uses arithmetic rather than simply `reversed(list(enumerate))`.

Comment: @DSM But this creates another list :)

Comment: @unwind: like thefourtheye pointed in a comment to his answer, returning -1 in not necessarily a good idea, as it is a valid index but would not point to a correct result.

Comment: @njzk2 Yeah, I was just considering that. I got it from `str.find()`, it returns -1 and nobody seems to have been hurt by that. I expect this to be used in an `if`, anyway.

Comment: This is very inefficient solution. Creating list of enumerated items may consume a lot of resources. Especially when you work with large iterators.

Comment: @JanBednařík D'oh, you're right, luckily the `list()` was trivial to optimize out. I think it's safe this way, right?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `enumerate` function to get an iterator which gives the current index and the item. We use that over the `reversed` `a`. So, if `j` is not `None`, we return the difference between the length of the sequence and the current index. We do everything as a generator expression, so we need to advance it with `next` function.

```
print next(len(a) - i for i, j in enumerate(reversed(a), 1) if j is not None)
# 9
```

Comment: I'd rather use `len(a) - i - 1` than `enumerate(..., 1)`, as I find it puzzling that enumerate should start at 1.

Comment: I would add `, -1` to the `next` to account for the case where all values are `None`

Comment: @njzk2 returning `-1` is not a good option since it is a valid list index in Python.

Comment: True. may be `None` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
max(index for index, item in enumerate(a) if item is not None)
```

Comment: crashes if all values are None

Comment: It should raise exception when you pass list full of None. That's Pythonic.

Comment: If I had to sit and read all of these without knowing what the actual problem was, this would be the clearest to me

Answer (score 2):

using [reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
a = ['a', 'b', None, 4, 5, None, 5, 4, None, 7, None, None, None, None]

reduce(lambda n, i : i if a[i] is not None else n, range(0, len(a)), -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just iterate with a flag:

```
target = 0
for i, val in enumerate(a):
    if val is not None:
        target = i
```

Answer (score 1):

You could start from the back and check to see if it isn't None.

```
x = next(x for x in reversed(seq) if x is not None)
```

Edit: I realized that you were looking for the index, not simply the value. The above code only gives the value of the last non-None element in the sequence.

You could add an enumerator to get the index, instead.

```
next(len(seq) - i for i, j in enumerate(reversed(seq), 1) if j is not None)
```

Comment: This would give the value, not the index.

Comment: Fixed. My bad. It now gives both pieces of information. Maybe someone someday will just want the value

Comment: your edited answer has already been given by thefourtheye, btw

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', None, 4, 5, None, 5, 4, None, 7, None, None, None, None]
>>> last_index=0
>>> for index, i in enumerate(a):
    if i is not None:
        last_index= index


>>> last_index
9
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Donno id this add anything to the current pool of answers:

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', None, 4, 5, None, 5, 4, None, 7, None, None, None, None]
>>> [i for i,v in enumerate(a) if v is not None][-1]
9
>>>
```

Comment: does not work if 7 is present several times in the list.

Comment: you should use `is not None` opposed to `!= None` [pep8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) programming recommendations. "Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not, never the equality operators."